# How to tell from a launch daemon if macOS is currently restarting?

Tags: c++, macos, launchd, reboot, launch-daemon

I have a launch daemon (written in C++) that runs on macOS. Is there a way to tell if the operating system is currently restarting?

(Or the moment after the user hit Apple Logo -> Restart and the OS is winding down.)

Comment: anyone? There must a way to know that. @pmdj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it if you are willing to dig into undocumented (but open sourced) stuff. This [blog post](https://dennisbabkin.com/blog/?t=macos-programming-shutdown-notifications-xcode-build-schemes-diagnose-memory-corruption-crashes#shutdown_notif) will show you an example, but basically you need to use `notify_register_mach_port`, `CFMachPortCreateWithPort` with some custom port names to register for notifications and then process them and remember last power event in a global state. I'll admit. Not as easy as it is on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of _NS_SYSTEM_RESTART key in the **notify** service.(use the launchd framework)

Comment: Thank you. But I'm struggling to find what is _NS_SYSTEM_RESTART. Would you mind showing a code sample?